# Descending Order Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

In this program I need to display an array list from an external file in descending order. Whenever I run the program though, I still get the same order of the original list. I just need help with the descending order part. I utilized the Collections methods to accomplish this task but I don't think I fully understand exactly what is going on whenever I call upon Collections, it just spits out the array list as brought in by the first array call. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I placed 4 stars at the end and beginning of the code in question.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ioStafford {



    public static void revOrder(String x[])
    {

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try(BufferedReader fr1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myImport.txt")))
        {

            //Create a new file for the reverse output if it doesn't exist
            File f1 = new File("myOutput.txt");

            //Code for new file creation
            if(!f1.exists())
            {
                f1.createNewFile();
            }

            //Initialize string variables
            String type;

            //Array List to hold text file
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();


            //Add text file contents to the array list
            while((type = fr1.readLine()) != null)
            {
                names.add(type);
            }

            //Display array list
            System.out.println("Below is the list of animals with a comma and in the original order:");
            System.out.println(names);

            ****//Display information in descending order
            Collections.sort(names, Collections.reverseOrder());
            System.out.println(names);****


            //Convert array list to string and replace commas
            String fornames = names.toString().replace("," , " ");

            //Display altered information
            System.out.println("Here is the list with the commas removed:");
            System.out.println(fornames);                                               
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
        System.out.println("Please utilize the file named myImport.txt please!");
        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a short example (maybe 4 animals) of what the code is producing? There is nothing wrong that I see with the sort.

Comment: Show what `names` contains.

Comment: What does myImport.txt contain? What is the output of the program? My guess is that it contains a single line containing the name of several animals, and that you thus have a single string in your list, since the code reads the file line by line and puts the whole line in the list.

Comment: My apologies. The text file contains cat,dog,bear,monkey. But you can replace that with anything. The important part is to change the order of a list of string values separated by a comma.

Comment: Below is the list of animals with a comma and in the original order:
[cat,monkey,dog,lion,bear]
[cat,monkey,dog,lion,bear]
Here is the list with the commas removed:
[cat monkey dog lion bear]

Answer (score -1):

Try this one in a place of

```
Collections.sort(names, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

:->

```
    Collections.sort(names, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Now I've seen comparators used. My question would then become do you have to use a comparator with the collections sort? Because my impression right now is that they are independent of each other.

Comment: Friend Did you try above method. I am sure it will work, i already tested that. And yes we need to give comparator to the Collections.sort(list,comparator) as a parameter if we have to sort the list of the objects. And if we want to sort in our own way.

Comment: This code did not work. Furthermore, I'm not really looking for a direct answer, I still want to learn and frankly I'm not going to just copy and paste code in to make this work. Thanks for the help though